# What steps can I take to fix a 'Cannot find module' error when running React in Visual Studio Code using 'npm start'?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

In visual studio code, I ran the code (npx create-react-app front) in a directory, and after installing it and going to the directory (cd front), I ran the code (npm start) or even (npm run start) but I got this error:

PS C:\MyFiles\University\4th\DataBase & Web\The Project\MERN\front> npm start

> front@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

The system cannot find the path specified.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1073
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\MyFiles\University\4th\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1070:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:923:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.2.0

I deleted the node_module folder and recreated it by npm install, I cleared the cashe, did the whole thing in a different directory.. nothing changed and I still get the same error. I even found this file and copied and created a directory for this address that was mentioned in the error (C:\MyFiles\University\4th\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js); but no luck.